# Change activity from button in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, android-fragmentactivity

Goodmorning everyone, I'm very new on android and I'd like to put an action of a button of a fragment... I'm using this way:

```
    Button butt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);



    butt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,newactivity.class);
            startActivity(int1);


            finish();



        }
    });
```

The problem is that I don't know where to place this action, if in the main activity class or in the import fragment class, the import fragment class is a list with buttons and I'd like each button to move to another activity.

This is the ImportFragment.class code:

```
    public class ImportFragment extends Fragment {
ListView listView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_import,container,false);



    return rootView;

}
```

}

This is the Main Activity code that lead to the fragment by a lateral navigation drawer:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;
Button enobutt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.enobtn);

SupportMapFragment sMapFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    sMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager rFm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(!sMapFragment.isAdded())
        rFm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, sMapFragment).commit();
    else
        rFm.beginTransaction().show(sMapFragment).commit();



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    android.app.FragmentManager fn = getFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sFm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(sMapFragment.isAdded())
         sFm.beginTransaction().hide(sMapFragment).commit();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fn.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,  new ImportFragment()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        if(!sMapFragment.isAdded())
        sFm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, sMapFragment).commit();
        else
             sFm.beginTransaction().show(sMapFragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;}
```

}

how can I do?

Comment: if you want to load activity from fragment then put that code inside your fragment oncreate

Comment: if the button is part of  fragement xml put the code in Fragments on CreateView

Comment: Can you give me an example of the code? because it seems not to work but maybe I'm doing something wrong. The button is a part of the xml fragment yes.. exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your fragment to

```
public class ImportFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    private Activity activity;

    public ImportFragment(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }    

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_import,container,false);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, newactivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
                activity.finish();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked thank you! I signed your as the correct question.. this didn't work and showed some error: 

        public ImportFragment(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }   

 , but the rest is right

Answer (score 3):

try this it can help you

```
butt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class));
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this.... i made the changes in your code

```
public class ImportFragment extends Fragment {
ListView listView;
@Nullable
@Override
enter code here

 Button butt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

 butt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent int1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,newactivity.class);
 startActivity(int1);
 finish();
 }
 });
 return rootView;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just simply have to add  onButtonClick in createView

and add following line

```
 startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), YourOtherActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a good question, but it's a concept issue and it depends entirely on what you want to do. If you want the button action in the fragment to be the same every time you post that fragment, you can leave the OnClickListener in this fragment. Otherwise put it in the activity using a callback method. (see [callback doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html))

Another good practice is to use the MVP pattern (Model View Presenter), to separate the views from the logic.